# error opening video .dat file

Tags: video, codecs

I am trying to play a video cd with VLC media player which has octet stream and `.dat` file extension but VLC media player is not able to play individual files from VCD.

I've tried:

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

and tried opening the file with videos but of no use how can I play the video in ubuntu.

I can play whole VCD in VLC player but not the "single" dat files separately as it opens in windows media player

Comment: `.dat` is a binary file - not typically a video - a `.dat` is a Windows binary, and i'm going to bet that you have to run that to decode the video CD and access the files themselves (which are likely actual video files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VLC, you're using the Media -> "Open Disc / Ctrl+D" option, and picking your cd player device?

Trying to open a single file on a video cd usually does not work, VLC has a special way to open vcd's "all at once."

Answer (score 1):

Rename **.dat** file to **.mpg**. I hope it works. If it doesn't help install Gxine player.

```
sudo apt-get install gxine
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need some extra codecs. Try this :

For i386 install codecs:

`sudo apt-get install w32codecs libdvdcss2`

For amd64 install codecs:

`sudo apt-get install w64codecs libdvdcss2`

Comment: Package libdvdcss2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source